# Unplug the /wireless tag from /wifi

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

I've been working recently with content falling under the heading *Radio Frequency*. I've noticed the tag [wireless](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wireless) is synonymous with [wifi](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi). In fact, it defaults to [wifi](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi), and this is reasonable considering its proper usage. But as for the [wireless](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wireless), I'd rather not have it a synonym of [wifi](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi).

The term *wireless* in its basic or original meaning denotes a communication technology, which doesn't employ a wire, in general. And what I would do is to make it stand for itself for the wireless communication in general. Moreover, I'd make it synonymous with a yet nonexistent tag [rf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rf), denoting [Radio Frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_frequency) technologies ranging from [bluetooth](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth) through [mobile](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile) to [satellite](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/satellite).

Take a look at the Wikipedia's entry for [Wireless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless). Also notice how the
[Network Engineers](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) have it organised:

- [wifi](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/ieee-802.11/synonyms) is synonymous there with [ieee-802.11](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/ieee-802.11/info)
- while [wireless](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/wireless/info) has this usage instruction:

  > For WiFi or 802.11 questions, please use the [ieee-802.11] tag. For
  >   questions about wireless networking, including any licensed or
  >   unlicensed RF medium used to provide point-to-point or
  >   point-to-multipoint network links.

Comment: Bear in mind that [networkengineering.se] will be considerably more knowledgeable on the various wireless communication protocols than your average U&L user. Whether we like it or not, the term 'WiFi' has become synonymous with 'wireless networking'. Yes, that's not strictly speaking correct, but be that as it may, that's how it's used.

Comment: It may be too late then.